# Get the height of soft nav bar in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, layout

I am rendering content at the same height of the screen in React Native (`Dimensions.get("window").height`), however when the Android phone has a soft navbar, some of the content gets hidden like so:

[image: Navbar]

On my phone, there is also a soft navbar, but it seems to function differently and does not cover the content, like so:

[image: Hard navbar]

What is the difference between these 2 navbars? I just want to find the height of the black navbar if it exists and then I can solve my problem. I have searched extensively and there seems to be no clear answer. Maybe my terminology is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Dimensions.get("window").height`, you can't safely calculate screen height from it. Different devices will have different navbars (obstructing and not, depending also on AndroidManifest), status bars, camera cutouts. React Native has [SafeAreaView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview) specifically for this purpose - you wrap your content in SafeAreaView which will provide paddings to make sure content doesn't overlap with those areas

Answer (score 3):

For those who have similar need, here is what i used to get the soft nav bar height. I was already using react navigation so react-native-safe-area-context came along with it.

```
import { Dimensions, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { initialWindowMetrics } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const { insets, frame } = initialWindowMetrics;
export const BOTTOM_NAV_BAR_HEIGHT = frame.height - WINDOW_HEIGHT- StatusBar.currentHeight
```

Comment: Works great for iOS, with notch or without it, and Android. Had to use `Dimensions.get("screen").height` though, because `Dimensions.get("window").height` vary on Android, some include the status bar, some don't.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import { Dimensions, StatusBar } from "react-native";

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const navbarHeight = screenHeight - windowHeight
```

Comment: Why did you import ```Platform```?

Comment: @SaidTorres, sorry that was a mistake, removed. Thanks!